# Upgrading to latest pip caused ValueError

Tags: python, pip, pypi

The latest upgrade to `pip` (using Python 3.5) causes the following error to occur for any `pip` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip3.5", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip import pep425tags
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 214, in <module>
    supported_tags = get_supported()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 162, in get_supported
    arch = get_platform()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py", line 119, in get_platform
    major, minor, micro = release.split('.')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I'm even unable to upgrade or uninstall. What caused this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and edited

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/pep425tags.py
```

at line 120.

Removed the `micro` value, and it now works again. Not sure what happened.